# Find Intersection index faces two mesh

Tags: python

I need to find in the object 1 the index of the polygon that does not intersect with the polygons of object 2.

[image]

Comment: Needs more detailed description. You have two objects and they are intersecting? Which index (1 to 5) do you want in the picture?

Comment: I need to find all the faces of object 1 that intersect with object 2.Sorry for this description, I do not know English well